# dccosx Fatal Error

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I would like to compile my Rad Studio XE8 Delphi project under Rad Studio Seattle.

Compiling for Win32 and Win64 platforms are success. But when I try to compile the project with OSX, I always got an compile error:

> [dccosx Fatal Error] F2084 Internal Error: AV0CAF8963-R00000014-0

If I try to compile a new Multi-Device-Application with a simple TButton, I got the same compile error also.

Answer (score 2):

That's an internal compiler error (ICU). It should not happen and you should submit a report to [Quality Portal](https://quality.embarcadero.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa).

A similar error was reported by Brian Hamilton at the Google+ Delphi Developers group: https://plus.google.com/104232310939175186229/posts/d5wv2nfsU7p

He believes that moving to a newer OSX SDK resolved the problem:

> Changing to OSX 10.8.3 sdk and fixed!

You might try that to see if it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your suggestion. 

I would have never thought that the SDK was the root of the problem.
I have a MacBookAir with the latest OS X version (10.10.5).

The Rad Studio Seattle used the SDK that came from this Mac, so I know the Seattle's dccosx compiler does not like the 10.10.5 SDK, but it worked fine on XE8 update 1.

I did try the following SDKs also:
   10.10:  worked!
   10.9.5: worked!
   10.9.2: worked!
   10.8.5: worked!